# Insert the contents of the variable in SED command

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I have an text file named **answer.txt**. And i'm trying to read the contents from a file and trying to insert in the below yaml file (`above 'kind:'`)

For that, I'm reading the file and assigning to a variable.
**file= 'cat answer.txt'**

If, I print this using echo, **echo $file** I can able to see the contents.

But, when i try to insert this in SED command, the actual variable itself is getting inserted but not the actual contents. I'm not sure, what i'm doing wrong here.

**Command** - `sed  '/kind/i $file' input`

**Yaml file name - input**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           upstream
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :1020
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-24T15:19:51Z"
  name: core
  namespace: system
  resourceVersion: "166"
  selfLink: /api/v1/system/configmaps/core
  uid: b80b35ad-8718-4e88-8asbef-bceb289d50ee
```

**After applying SED command,**

```
apiVersion: v1
    data:
      Corefile: |
        .:53 {
            errors
            health
            kubernetes cluster.in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
               pods insecure
               upstream
               fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
               ttl 30
            }
            prometheus :1020
            forward . /etc/resolv.conf
            cache 30
            loop
            reload
            loadbalance
        }
    $file
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: "2020-01-24T15:19:51Z"
      name: core
      namespace: system
      resourceVersion: "166"
      selfLink: /api/v1/system/configmaps/core
      uid: b80b35ad-8718-4e88-8asbef-bceb289d50ee
```

Could some one please correct me as i'm a beginner? 
Thanks in advance

**Operating System - MAC**

Comment: use double quotes to allow for the variable to be expanded inside the `sed` command

Comment: If you want to run variables in `sed` comand use double quotes instead of single quotes.